# How to display the selected value from the dropdown

Tags: javascript, laravel, view, laravel-blade, policies

What i want to achieve is when i click on the dropdown value, for example approved , The dropdown should be dissapear and the selected value'approve' need to be display.

```
balde

<td>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Status
                      </button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        @if($leave->status_id == 1)
                          <button class="dropdown-item" data-url="{{route('leave.update', $leave->id)}}" data-status_id="2" onclick="updateleave(this);removedropdown(this)">Approve</button>
                          <button class="dropdown-item" data-url="{{route('leave.update', $leave->id)}}" data-status_id="3" onclick="updateleave(this);removedropdown(this)">Rejected</button>
                        @else
                          {{$leave->statustype->status}}
                        @endif
                    </div>
                  </td> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

  function updateleave(el) {
    let data = {
          status_id:$(el).data('status_id')
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: $(el).data('url'),
      type: 'PUT',
      data: {
        _token:CSRF_TOKEN,
        leave:data
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(result) {
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error);
          } else {
            location.reload();
          }
      },
      error: function(err) {
          alert('something went wrong');
      }
    });
  }

  function removedropdown(el) {
      // to remove the dropdown after select 
  }
```

so this it is .Im stuck how shall i proceed.
[image]

Comment: do you want the drop down to disappear AFTER the ajax call succeeded, or immediately after the button (approved or rejected) is clicked?

Comment: immediately after the button is clicked. i have tried click and the data in database can be updated when i click them. So now i just want the dropdown to disappear after click and show the selected item

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the functions using `onclick` attribute, but I recommend using an event handler for that.

So you could `onclick="updateleave(this);removedropdown(this)"` but, I recommend:

```js
$('.dropdown-item').click((event) => {
  updateleave(event.target);
  removedropdown(event.target);
});

function updateleave(el) {
  ///ajax stuff here
}

function removedropdown(el) {
  // to remove the dropdown after select 
  const dropdown = el.closest('.dropdown'); //get dropdown
  const selected = $(`<label>${$(el).text()}</label>`); //create selected label    
  selected.appendTo($(dropdown).parent()); //append label to dropdown's parent before...
  dropdown.remove(); //...removing dropdown
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
balde

<td>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Status
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <button class="dropdown-item" data-url="{{route('leave.update', $leave->id)}}" data-status_id="2">
        Approve
      </button>
      <button class="dropdown-item" data-url="{{route('leave.update', $leave->id)}}" data-status_id="3">
        Rejected
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: ok lemme try but i did if else inside the div button but the dropdown doest not disappear

Comment: i did but the dropdown is still enabled .it does not dissapear

Comment: I honestly don't know what you mean by *i did if else inside the div button*. Is it not `<div class="dropdown">` what you want to disappear? please update your question with what you've tried and any new info

Comment: i have updated my codes and the current output is as the picture.I able to see the approve by clicking the dropdown. i did not use the javascript here .only if and else in the blade. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: look, I can help you with the JS, but I've never worked with laravel. That said, that`@if-else` structure you're using seems to never hide the drop-down, it's just gonna hide *the buttons in the drop-down* when the leave's status ID is not 1. Finally, if you can use the `leave` variable to conditionally render some html elements and not others, then you don't need to show/hide/remove html with JS, just use blade's capabilities for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
//use condition in blade file 
//if status is Approvethen show selected Approve
//send id with onclick function like
onclick="approve(\'' + row.id + '\')" 
// in ajax
 function approve(id) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '',
        text: "confirmation message",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonColor: 'No'
    }) if (result.value) {
            approveFunction(id, 'approve');
        }

}
 function approveFunction (id, status) {
    axios({method: 'post',
        url: baseUrl + '',//route here
        data: {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), id: id, status: status}
    })
           success: function(data) {
                       alert("sucess");
                    }
```